# Installing a local FTP Server with K8S / Minikube, and accessing it with Filezilla

Tags: kubernetes, ftp, kubernetes-ingress

I'm trying to install a FTP server with Kubernetes based on [this repo](https://github.com/aledv/kubernetes-ftp).

I also use Traefik as Ingress.

Everything seems fine, and I can I connect FTP Server with cluster-ip, but I can't make it work with a local domain like ftp.local

Here are my K8S files:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  annotations:
    reloader.stakater.com/auto: "true"
  labels:
    app: ftp-local
  name: ftp-local
  namespace: influx
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: ftp-local
  strategy:
    type: Recreate
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: ftp-local
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: ftp-local
        image: fauria/vsftpd
        resources:
          limits:
            memory: "128Mi"
            cpu: "500m"
        ports:
        - containerPort: 21
          protocol: TCP
          name: "ftp-server"
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: "/home/vsftpd"
          name: task-pv-storage
        env:
        - name: FTP_USER
          value: "sunchain"
        - name: FTP_PASS
          value: "sunchain"
        #- name: PASV_ADDRESS
        #  value: "127.0.0.1"
        #- name: PASV_MIN_PORT
        #  value: "21100"
        #- name: PASV_MAX_PORT
        #  value: "21110"
      volumes:
      - name: task-pv-storage
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: task-pv-claim
---

kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: task-pv-claim
  namespace: influx
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 3Gi
---
kind: PersistentVolume
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: task-pv-volume
  namespace: influx
  labels:
    type: local
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 10Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  hostPath:
    path: "/tmp/data"
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: ftp-local
  namespace: influx
  labels:
    app: ftp-local
spec:
  ports:
  - name: "21"
    port: 21
    targetPort: 21
  selector:
    app: ftp-local
  type: NodePort
---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ftp-ingress
  namespace: influx
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: traefik
spec:
  rules:
  - host: ftp.local
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
         serviceName: ftp-local
         servicePort: 21
```

I also have a line in /etc/hosts that like that:

```
127.0.0.1      ftp.local
```

What am I missing ?

Comment: I think the issue is because ingress is published with port 80. Don't know how to change it

Comment: FTP server in a container is an odd thing... You'd have to mount a volume to share, thus limiting the server to a single host, so why use kubernetes?

Comment: @cricket_007 m'y whole system is under k8s, and k8s can also manage statefull app. Maybe it is just easier to deploy once working ...

Comment: It doesn't migrate the volumes for you, is my point.

Comment: Is there really a thing like an ingress for FTP? I have never heard about such a thing. Why would you need an ingress for this? Anyways If you define your service as NodePort it will open a port on your machine/VM, in your case 21. The ingress won't be able to use the same port (except the controller is running on another machine). Can you connect to the FTP by using the IP Address of the Kubernetes machine (NodeIP)?

Comment: @whymatter yes I can

Comment: Okay so then you should be able to remove the ingress, and only use the node ip. How you do the DNS resolution has nothing to do with an ingress. Can you put the Node IP Address in the `/etc/hosts` file instead of localhost and test if the connection now works?

Comment: Yes but nodeip change each time I redeploy ftp server . Not so great. Anyway, I can test it

Comment: Wait by node IP I mean the physical address of that virtual machine so non of the cluster IPs like the 10.x.x.x ip address.

Comment: my cluster is installed directly on my ubuntu, with vm-driver=none, so I guess I can use 127.0.0.1

Comment: So why would you then have to change the node IP every time you redeploy the server

Comment: You didn't really answer my question. Why did you start managing things in Kubernetes? You have one machine. If you simply want to programmatically declare all your apps in a config file, there's better alternatives out there (e.g. NixOS, Chef/Ansible/Salt, Snapcraft), and you don't have to worry about allocation of network, memory, or disk

Comment: Alternatively, there's Nomad w/ exec or system driver + Consul for health checks + Vault for Secrets and you can manage them all with Terraform

Comment: @cricket_007 sorry for delay, I manage my infrastructure via k8s because I need my infrastructure to be scalable and to orchestrate my microservices, but this is out of the scope of the question. K8S is more than only scaling. This is also useful for stateful apps. In my case, it is just more practical to have everything under k8s, I'll just take more time to figure out how to implement it. Also for my functional tests, I need to deploy my infrastructure including FTP server on CI stage.

Comment: Terraform and Vmware can also do stateful apps just fine. You cannot scale an FTP server

Comment: yes, this is true, but it would bring me 2 extra techs in my stack for a single FTP server

Answer (score 2):

At first, link to repo you used was created/updated **2-3 years ago**.

Many newest Kubernetes features require `SSL` for communication. That's the reason why `SFTP` is easier to apply in Kubernetes.
Another thing, you are using `Minikube` with `--driver=none` which have some restrictions. All neccesary information about `none` driver are described [here](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/reference/drivers/none/).

There was already similar question regarding FTP Filezilla in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50289736/how-to-access-google-kubernetes-engine-ftp-server-by-filezilla).

As workaround you can consider using `hostPort` or `hostNetwork`.

Many configuration aspects depends on if you want to use [Acitve or Passive FTP](https://titanftp.com/2018/08/23/what-is-the-difference-between-active-and-passive-ftp/).

FTP requires two TCP connection to work. Second connection is established using random port. I doesn't look compatible with `Services` concept. `SFTP` requires only one connection.

As another solution you could consider use `SFTP`. You can find many articles in the web with information that its better to use SFTP instead of FTP. For example [Tibco docs](https://docs.tibco.com/pub/mftis/8.2.1/doc/html/GUID-14685E58-709C-455B-ADE1-A0A6A2A608B9.html) or [this article](https://www.vandyke.com/products/securefx/sftp.html)

You can check Information about [SFTP server using OpenSSH](https://github.com/emberstack/docker-sftp) and try this github [SFTP example](https://gist.github.com/jujhars13/1e99cf110e5df39d4ae3c7fef81589f8).

[Here](https://wiki.filezilla-project.org/Howto) you can find information abut using `SFTP` in `FileZilla`.